# translucent dark mask/overlay over all screen, except <nav> when focused on element inside <nav>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div id="translucent-mask">` that I want to cover all screen, except everything inside `<nav>` **if and only if when focused** on one of my `<nav>` bar `<li>` elements (they have tabindex) so I can focus in them:

```
<nav>    
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li onclick="location.href='#/work'" tabindex="1">Work</li>
        <li onclick="location.href='#/about'" tabindex="2">About
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li onclick="location.href='#/1'">Sub Menu 1</li>
                <li onclick="location.href='#/2'">Sub Menu 2</li>
                <li onclick="location.href='#/3'">Sub Menu 3</li>
                <li onclick="location.href='#/4'">Sub Menu 4</li>
                <li onclick="location.href='#/5'">Sub Menu 5</li>
            </ul>  
        </li>
           //more li elements...
</nav>
```

So this is the div: `<div id="translucent-mask"></div>`

So I try the pseudo class focus on my menu-list `li` elements:

```
  nav ul li:focus #translucent-mask {
        background: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

but it doesn't applies the styles, please help.

Hopefully there's a way to make this in CSS + HTML without JavaScript but if you know a solution in JS as well it is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
#translucent-mask {
    opacity: 0;
}

nav ul li:focus ~ #translucent-mask {
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li onclick="location.href='#/work'" tabindex="1">Work</li>
        <li onclick="location.href='#/about'" tabindex="2">About
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li onclick="location.href='#/1'">Sub Menu 1</li>
                <li onclick="location.href='#/2'">Sub Menu 2</li>
                <li onclick="location.href='#/3'">Sub Menu 3</li>
                <li onclick="location.href='#/4'">Sub Menu 4</li>
                <li onclick="location.href='#/5'">Sub Menu 5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <div id="translucent-mask"></div>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/fe4w9att/4/)**

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for help, I see the demo and it works but I pasted more code about my project I don't know why it doesn't work in my project: http://jsbin.com/naqogizeyi/edit?html,css,output  please help!

Answer (score 0):

So the css approach didn't work for my specific use case so I had to do it with vanilla JavaScript:

```
function dimScreen(){
    document.getElementById('translucent-mask').style.display = "block";
}
```

This is the element in css:

```
#translucent-mask {
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: none;
}
```

Now when I click in some li element in the nav I hade the dimScreen() function which dims the screen.

```
        <li onclick="location.href='#/about'; dimScreen()" tabindex="2">About
```

and my div is outside of nav bar:

`<div id="translucent-mask"></div>`